# Next.js - Redux provider cancels all the CSS (Tailwind) on the page

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm creating a chatting web-app with Next.js and have drilled props much. Decided to switch to Redux, and now I'm trying to create the store, provider, and stuff. But when I added the provider to the body in the layout.tsx, the whole CSS I had on the page disappeared, yet the functionality is the same. Also, I got it once working fine, but I really changed nothing, just resaved the file.

When CSS disappears on the main page, the other page called 'auth' gets 3 hydration errors, but the CSS remains the same.

When I had no error that time, everything looked and worked fine.

The store and slicer files are kinda empty right now, can it be relted to this?

provider.tsx:

```js
'use client';

import React from "react";
import { store } from "../store";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export function ReduxProvider({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    return <Provider store={store}> {children} </Provider>
}
```

chattingSlice.ts:

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { initScriptLoader } from 'next/script';


const initialState = {
    value: {
        message: ''
    }
}

export const chattingSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'chatting',
    initialState,
    reducers: {

    }
})
```

layout.tsx (the main page):

```js
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { ReduxProvider } from '@/redux/features/provider';
import { store } from '@/redux/store';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Rask - Chats',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ReduxProvider>
          {children}
        </ReduxProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

layout.tsx (auth page):

```js
import '../globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { ReduxProvider } from '@/redux/features/provider'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Rask - Welcome',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
      <ReduxProvider>
          {children}
      </ReduxProvider></body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

First, I had no provider on the auth page, but the problem hasn't been solved (idk, if it's related to the issue)

The hydration errors and file tree:
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCdzc.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45BOG.png)

[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4QgH.png)
[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqLLx.png)